# How does portaudio custom datatypes work?

Tags: c, portaudio

I am working with the portaudio lib for c and c++ on a small project and i came across their custom datatypes they use as sample types and i have no clue how the definition of the types work.

I have tried googling the code but no results show what i have experienced.

When they define the datatype they use the the #define preprocessor function to define it like so.

```c
typedef unsigned long PaSampleFormat

#define paFloat32 ((PaSampleFormat) 0x00000001)
```

Then my question is how does the `((PaSampleFormat) 0x00000001)` part work when you use it as a datatype.

Comment: It's simply an integer cast to a long. Then they name this integer float, because why not. And that's that...

Comment: @Lundin not quite. Read the portaudio documentation. `paSampleFormat` is a data type indicating what data format a sample buffer represents and `paFloat32` is one of the possible values for this (other values are e.g. `paUInt8`or `paint32`. No idea why the authors did it that way (probably varying `enum` bit lengths across different platforms would have affected portability?), I probably would have used an `enum` to begin with